# How to distribute cell height evenly within a row spanning two cells vertically?

Tags: css

I have a table with the following html structure:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=2>A (This is a dynamic column. I don't know its height).</td>
  <td>B</td>
  <td rowspan=2>D</td>
  <td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>F</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If the height of cell A is 200px, cells B, C, E and F would distribute themselves evenly to a height of 100px when viewed with Firefox 19.0 browser. However, Google Chrome 25.0 would display the same table with cells B and E having a height just sufficient to contain its content and cells C and F occupying the remaining space.

[DEMO in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASQJG/3/)

My question is, how do I distribute the height of these cells evenly without specifying the cell height in CSS? **Edit**: My objective is to have the internal cells distribute evenly when cell A changes in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this same issue. Here's how my data table looks in IE8 & FF23
The second image is how it looks in Chrome & Opera (notice the blue highlighting how the bottom row is expanded to fill the height).

[image: IE8 & FF23]

[image: Chrome & Opera12]

The answer is you can't as far as I have tried. It's how the underlying browser treats the standards. IE & FF will divide the cells on the right evenly where Chrome & Opera just expand the bottow cell to fill the height. The best you can do is vertically align the bottom row to the top so at least all the data is together.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height for td in css. Hence you dont need to specify height for `#A`.

If you want to set the height of `cell A` to 100px, set `td` height to 50px

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASQJG/1/)

Comment: My objective is to have the internal cells distribute evenly when cell A changes in height. Sorry, if I am not clear enough.

Comment: By setting the td height, you are also setting the height of cell A( which is twice the height of td). This will work for the tables with the structure you provided.

Comment: The height of cell A is suppose to be dynamic, not static. So, I wouldn't know what height to set for td.

Comment: You can set the height for td dynamically just like setting height for cell A, can't you?

Comment: For the benefit of your understanding, I have remove the height specification for cell A. Please take a look at the JsFiddle again to understand what I mean by dynamic.